# Ajax is not successful using Express

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I tried many tutorials about using Ajax in Express, but failed.
My purpose is when clicking on a button, the current page can receive data from server without refreshing, so I want to use Ajax in JQuery.

The JQuery code is:

```
$('#follow').click(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/follow',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: '{"data": "TEST"}',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        var ret = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $('#carousel-name').html(ret.msg);
        console.log('Success: ')
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
        $('#carousel-name').html('Error connecting to the server.');
    },
});});
```

And the server.js:

```
app.get('/follow', function(req, res){
    console.log('request received');
   res.send(JSON.stringify(['hello']));

});
```

What the client side received is just the Json data, also the URl is change to http://localhost:4444/follow

So what is the right way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're really trying to use JSONP like your ajax call inidicates, then the response in Express must be a different type of response as a JSONP response is very different than a JSON response.

```
app.get('/follow', function(req, res){
    console.log('request received');
    res.jsonp(['hello']);      // use .jsonp() here

});
```

Express doc: http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.jsonp

In your Ajax call, you also don't have to parse the JSON because jQuery will parse it for you automatically.  In fact, trying to parse it when it is already parsed will throw an exception.

Also see this other answer: [How to use jsonp with node.js express](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22162338/816620)

---

Note: unless you need old browser support, you may just want to use CORS on your Express server rather than use JSONP (enable your server for cross origin requests).