# Node.js API MongoDB request only working on localhost

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm working on an APP and I am requesting data from an API that run on a *Node.js* which query a *MongoDB*.

The app run when I access it from localhost but not from an external source. Its hard to tell whats the error since I'm using a mobile device to access the server.
When I try to access it from elsewhere I can see the main page but not the data from the APP

At first I could not even get it from localhost so I found that code and its working on localhost.

```
app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
});
```

And yes this is not secure.

***EDIT***

I want to be able to connect to my pc from anywhere and use the app.

**The Node.js** server is as follow;

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); 
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/www'));
app.listen(80);
```

**My APP**

```
   var express = require('express');
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var assert = require('assert');
    var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/site'; 
    var app = express();

//This was added because I was getting cross domain error even on local network
        app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
        next();
        });
   // NOT SECURE

    var findIco = function(db, callback) {
        db.collection('footIco').find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
            if (err) return callback(err, null);
            return callback(null, docs);
        });
    }

app.get('/icons', function(req, res){
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send(err);
   }
    findIco(db, function(err, icons) {
        if(err){
          res.status(500).json(err);
        }
        else{
            if(!icons){
              res.status(204).send();
              }
              else{
                  res.json(icons);
                  }
               db.close();
               return;
            }
        });  
    });
  });
```

**The JavaScript**;

```
var app = angular.module('app', ["ngSanitize"]);
app.controller('footIconCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/icons'  // <--- Will only work locally
  //url: 'http://my.ip.addr.:8080/icons'  // <--- Will only work extrernally
})
  .then(function(icons) {
  console.log(icons);
    $scope.icons = icons.data;
  })
  .catch(function(errRes) {
    // Handle errRess
  });
});
```

I have also tried;

```
app.controller('footIconCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

var url = 'http://my.ip.add.res:8080/icons&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

 $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
    //what do I do here?
     $scope.icons=data;
});
});
```

Getting the same result!

**Edit#2**

Just found out that it is Mongo that refuses the connection. I have changed all my ip from localhost to my real IP and I get this error in the Node.js console

```
{ [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 111.222.333.444:27017]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 111.222.333.444:27017' }
```

Of course this is not my real IP but I don't feel like getting hacked tonight! And I don't understand why this will work locally only if localhost is provided as the address and in the other end it will only work externally if I provide my WAN IP.

Comment: You either have to forward your ports or be connected to the same local network with the device you're trying to connect with. Also, requesting `http://localhost:8080` from your external device wouldn't make sense as `localhost == 127.0.0.1`, which means *this computer/device*. Your post is not crystal clear, but from what I understand you're able to connect when those headers are present? If that's the case, that means CORS (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) has to be `*` enabled for you to request that resource.

Comment: Yes i need these headers for the app to work.
so i would have to use the full adresse. Will try that out, Thank you!

Comment: If you need those headers when developing, I suggest that you put them in an if-clause. E.g: `if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') { // add headers... }`. When you then deploy your script to production, you'd do `export NODE_ENV=production` then start your app and those headers won't be added (it is *highly recommended* that you set `NODE_ENV` to `production` when you deploy)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions you can try:

1. Use your current solution with setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. This will **violate** the **important built-in** CORS policy of **every modern browsers**. Your system will not be secured since it's opening all APIs to the world.
2. Change the implementation of node.js API to support cross origin request for **only `/icons` API**, and **only accept GET requests from SOME IP ADDRESSES**. On angular part, use [$http.jsonp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) to call the api. Your system will be more secured. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231579/how-to-use-jsonp-with-node-js-express) to know about the implementation of `jsonp` on node.js.

Comment: I have added my full code. I'm new to this node deal so im not sure how to implement a secure and working code.

Comment: Well. So just follow the SO link to use res.jsonp and $http.jsonp.

Comment: app.controller('footIconCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

var url = 'http://my.ip.adr.ess:8080/icons&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

 $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
  
     $scope.icons=data;
});
});

I get the exact same result.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your node server is running on your computers `internalIp` - This could be `192.168.0.10`, also on your `external source` (im assuming this is a browser on a phone ), make sure you're referencing the `192.168.0.10:PORT_NUMBER_HERE` (your internal IP, check this http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/i/internip.htm ) in your html, or php, or whatever language you are using.

If you are trying to access the `API` calls from an `App`, then make sure any `url's` in the source code are referencing your `internal ip`. Also make sure your device that you're running the `API` call from is connected to the same internet network as your node server.

Hope this helps as you've provided very little information to where your trying to access the `api` call from.