# Messenger Platform Webview AJAX to app.js on close [node.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am designing a bot for a restaurant and a requirement of this is it needs to send a receipt at the end. Most of the transactions are done through a webview, viewing the menu and ordering.

When the user clicks "Finish Order", the webview should close and the bot should message the user with a receipt template, detailing their order. To do this, I need to communicate with app.js through the webview. I have attempted to do an AJAX request but it seems it's stopped by the cross-domain policy (instantly cancels the request).

My code for the ajax request is thus...

```
$('#end_order').on('click', function(){
            MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser(function success() {
                MessengerExtensions.getContext('[PAGEID]', function success(thread_context){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/new-order?access_token=[MYPAGEACCESSTOKEN]",
                        data: { sessionID: "123971230987", order: order },
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        success: function(res){
                            console.log("SUCCESS: " + res);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }, function error(err) {
                // an error occurred
            });
        });
```

I've looked into jsonP (Json with "padding") but I can't find the context or the syntax on how to apply it to my node application. Any/all advice is appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231579/how-to-use-jsonp-with-node-js-express

Comment: @luschn That doesn't seem to help me, as that's the node app reading the response to an ajax request, or otherwise. I can't send a request to the node app because any request I try to send is instantly cancelled, as per the cross-domain policy.

Comment: What error are you seeing in the console when `requestCloseBrowser()` is called? CORS would be a strange error to occur since you aren't trying to load anything in the browser.

Comment: @amuramoto No error from the requestCloseBrowser(), that works perfectly. It's a part of the [Messenger Extensions APK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions) - It's the XMLHttpRequest that doesn't post due to CORS.

Comment: Have you tried adding ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN header in your response? For APIs it’s pretty common to set to * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin